# Login using PHP and JavaScript from SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a drop-down login panel (I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7), where I want the user to input the username and password used during registration.

If login is successful I want the user to be redirected to another page called `profile.php` else if login is not successful an error message will appear on the login panel footer. Here is my html code for the panel:

```
<li class="nav-link dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Login</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <div style="width:300px;">
      <div class="panel-heading text-center" style="color:black;">LOGIN</div>
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <label for="email">username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
        <label for="email">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
        <br>
        <a href="#" style="color:blue; list-style:none;">Forgotten password?</a><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;" id="login" value="login">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer" id="login_msg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

here is my javascript login code:

```
$("#login").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var u_name = $("#username").val();
  var pass = $("#password").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      userLogin: 1,
      userUname: u_name,
      userPassword: pass
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == "truejsdhfkh") {
        window.location.href = "profile.php";
      } else {
        $("#login_msg").html(data);
      }
    }
  })
})
```

here is my php login code:

```
<?php
// connect to the database
include "db.php";
//session start
session_start();
//login page
if(isset($_POST['userLogin'])){

    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userUname']);
    $passwrd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['userPassword']);


    if(empty($uname) || empty($passwrd)){
        echo "
        <div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a><b>Please fill in all fields!</b>
        </div>
    ";
    exit();
    }else{
        $passwrd = md5($passwrd);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = '$u_name' AND passwrd = '$password'";
        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($run_query);
        if($count == 1){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);
            $_SESSION["uid"] = $row["user_id"];
            $_SESSION["uname"] = $row["username"];
            echo "truejsdhfkh";
    }
    }

}
?>
```

I am using a phpMyAdmin SQL database. The database name is `user_info` with the following columns:
(`user_id`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `passwrd`, `mobile`, `home_town`)

When I click the login button nothing happens please help?

Comment: You have to check console log.

Comment: how do i do that? @rawathemant

Comment: you must not store your passwords as md5 hashes, it is not a secure way to hash passwords. Also you should have a look at prepared statements which are a better and safer way to prevent sql injections than mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: where is defined the var `$u_name` you use in your query ? (perhaps it is a typo and you mean `$uname` ?)

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ should i do somethiing like this or what do you mean
$u_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["userUname"]);
    $password = md5($_POST["userPassword"]);

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ i corrected the $uname but still when i click the login button nothing is happening

Comment: ok, next thing to do : check your php logs to see if there is an error

Comment: php code doesnt contain any error

Comment: add an error callback into your ajax function like this : `error: function (xhr, status, error) { var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); alert(err.error); }` this will alert something if there is an error with the request

Comment: nothing is happening after i add that code

Answer (score 0):

You have two typo in your query. The first one was pointed out in the comments and seems like it was corrected by you. The second one is that you are passing $password when it doesn't exists. You should pass $passwrd .

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = '$uname' AND passwrd = '$passwrd'";

                                                    ^^                    ^^
//Typos                                          $u_name                $password
```

Sorry for taking too much space but I can't add comments.

Comment: still not working! i at least should be getting the error when i dont enter the username and password but still nothing is happening when i click the button

Comment: @collinsnjoka I tested it on my webserver, the login and the error display both work for me. Can you test it by making a simple html post form and this php code? That will help you to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function login() {
  //THE GET ID
  $.post( "/login.php", {userLogin: 1, userUname: u_name,userPassword: pass })
    .done(function( data ) {
      if (data == "truejsdhfkh") {
        window.location.href = "profile.php";
      } else {
        $("#login_msg").html(data);
      };
    });
}
```